# Execute command after every 1 minute in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timer, serial-port, timertask

I am working on a project with serial port.

I want to Write command to serial port after every 1, 2 or x minute.

```
serialport1.write("AT");
```

I have a Timer and I am show Date and Time in my form with that timer . If there is any way to send above command with that timer or by using datetime.

I read lot of posts but didn't understand, as I am starter in C# language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use Timer and Set Interval for Timer in Property window...!

You can Execute Command on the Timer Tick Event and update Date Time use Two Timer Control one for executing command with one or two minute and other timer use execute every second for Datetime updation...!

Timer Tick Event Execute Every time Based on timer Interval...!

U can Start and Stop Timer Easy Way like **Timername.Start();** and **Timername.Stop();**

like Below :

```
Timer1_Tick()
{
   serialport1.write("AT");
}

  Timer2_Tick()
   {
     //Datetimeupdation code
   }
```

Note: Timer Tick Event Execute you must start the Timer by using **Timername.Start();**

Comment: OK. I got it but can I use one timer for both thing.. command run and date time... and two or more timers may heavy the software or not.?

Comment: You can execute heavy functionality in timer may heavy the software loading time...! follow Close Form event to must stop the timer.This two functionality may be ok for execute on the timer...!